# validateについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

#### 前提・実現したいこと

投稿の際に昨日以前に日付設定した場合に投稿できないように機能を実装したい。

railsで指定した日付以降に開ける投稿アプリを作っています。
上記の機能を実装中に以下のエラーメッセージが発生しました。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
ArgumentError in ItemsController#create

comparison of Time with nil failed
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```
Ruby

validate :judge_future

private

def judge_future
 return unless  open_day
  if (Time.now + 1.day) >= open_day#もし今日より過去ならerror
   errors.add(:open_day, 'は明日以降に設定してください。')
  end
end
```

対処法がわかる方いましたコメントお願いします。

Comment: ログにリクエストで送信されたパラメータや詳細なエラー箇所などが表示されているはずです。質問を編集して追記してください。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/118821

Comment: teratail のコードでは return 行が comment out されてますね。

Answer (score 1):

comparison of Time with nil failed　というエラーは、

```
if (Time.now + 1.day) >= open_day
```

の条件判定で起きていると考えられます。なぜなら、質問のコードの中で比較(comparison)が行われているのは、この部分だけだからです。

メッセージを直訳すると「Time と nil　の比較に失敗した」ですから、『open_dayがnil』がエラーの原因です。

質問のコードには、open_dayに代入しているところがありません。
・open_dayに何らかの値を代入する部分が抜けている
・質問のコードではないところでopen_dayに値が代入されるはずだったが、それが機能していない。
といった事が考えられます。

質問の『railsで指定した日付』がopen_dayなのだと思われますが、日付を指定している部分のコードが示されていませんので、対処法は誰にも判らないでしょうね。

Comment: `return unless  open_day`というnilチェックのコードがあるので`open_day`がnilなら`if (Time.now + 1.day) >= open_day`にはたどり着きません。`open_day`は変数ではなくカラムに紐付いた属性でしょうからバリデーションのメソッド内に代入するコードがないのは通常です。